# Is it possible to dynamically name formControls in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

In a nutshell, what I would love to accomplish if it were possible is this

```
export class MyComponent{

    Data: any;
    {{Data.formCtrlName}} = new formControl(); //this here

}
```

with `Data` being populated by a `JSON` object that looks something like this.

```
{
    "id"          : "someId",
    "name"        : "someName",
    "formCtrlName": "nameForControl",  //using this result as the name for the control
    "etc"         : "etc",
    "etc"         : "etc"
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  So far all the docs I've been coming across show how to dynamically create a form element that's already defined.  What I'm trying to do is insert the name for the `formControl` from my data.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the constructor or inside `ngOnInit`. Just make sure that `Data` is not null when you access it

```
export class MyComponent implement OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    this[this.Data.formControlName] = new FormControl();
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. this[this.Data.formControlName] is undefined on init and later becomes the form control, which is then unnamed which throws an errors b/c there is nothing to bind [formControlName] to in the template.

Comment: @RAC Didn't you see what I said **just make sure that Data is not null when you access it** ?

Comment: So you should probably add that to the answer. Make it a complete answer.

Comment: @RAC What are you talking about? My answer did mention that